# foreach loop finally

Tags: c#, loops, try-catch, finally

I have a foreach loop that has try catch and finally. it goes through files in a folder and  finally deletes them all....but now if i have two files, as it is deleting all( i need to delete all because of app functionality) it will not go though second file. is it possible to let foreach loop finish then delete all files in foreach method here is an example:

```
foreach (DirectoryInfo directory in directories)
{
    foreach (FileInfo file in directory.GetFiles("*.csv"))
    {
        try
        {
           //do something with file

        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //catch exception
        }
        finally
        {
            if (!IsFileLocked(file))
            {
                string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Test");
                foreach (string filetoDelete in files)
                {
                    File.Delete(filetoDelete);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

hope it is clear enough.

Comment: Delete each file as you loop through them, else the loop isn't required.

Comment: Better use FOR loop instead of foreach.

Comment: but then i have images relating to that file i need images cleared as well

Comment: Keep the file delete code section outside the directory loop it will delete all files at once and if you want to delete files after each directory checking keep it outside the fileinfo loop.

Comment: What is the relation between `C:\Test` and `directories`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not very sure if I'm right understood what you're asking for, but to me it seems solution pretty trivial, like this:

```
foreach (DirectoryInfo directory in directories)
{
    foreach (FileInfo file in directory.GetFiles("*.csv"))
    {
        try
        {
            //do something with file

         }

         catch (Exception e)
         {
               //catch exception
          }
     }

     foreach(FileInfo fileToDeleteInfo...)
     {
          try
          {
               if (!IsFileLocked(fileToDeleteInfo))
               {
                  string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Test");
                  foreach (string filetoDelete in files)
                  {
                       File.Delete(filetoDelete);
                  }
                }


            }
          catch(...)
          {... }
     }
```

In other words, move file deletion from the second (nested) `foreach` into the new one.

If this is not what you're asking for, please clarify.

Answer (score 5):

Your code:

1. Loops through given set of directories and for each of them:
2. Gets "*.csv" files in that dir and with each file:
3. Does something and then:
4. Deletes files from **"C:\Test"**.

Shouldn't you be deleting the file you just processed, or at least files from the dir you are currently processing, not files from "C:\Test"?